# Why is there a "No overload matches this call" error when passing a reactive prop?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, overloading, vue-props

In my main application I defined

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon"
const now = ref(DateTime.now())
const maxCityNameSize = ref(0)
```

The variables are then passed to a component:

```js
<time-bar :now="now" :maxCityNameSize="maxCityNameSize"></time-bar>
```

In that component, they are defined as

```
const props = defineProps({
    now: { type: DateTime },
    maxCityNameSize: { type: Number },
})
```

My code works as expected, but I get for the `props` above a TypeScript error I cannot understand:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: string[]): { readonly [x: string]: any; }', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: ComponentObjectPropsOptions<Data>): { readonly [x: string]: Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined; }', gave the following error.ts(2769)

runtime-core.d.ts(322, 53): The expected type comes from property 'now' which is declared here on type 'ComponentObjectPropsOptions<Data>'
```

I have never seen that error (despite having used props a lot) - what does it mean?

For the sake of completeness, I added another reactive variable passed as a prop which does not trigger the error.

When searching for the reason, it was generally pointed that the error some from either the wrong number of parameters to a function (not applicable), or by a type mismatch (I do not see a type mismatch either).

Comment: Really? When I have the [same code](https://tsplay.dev/mqyDYm), I get "Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type." and fiddling a bit more with `new DateTime()` reveals that `DateTime` has a private constructor. You can't assign a private constructor to a public one, so there is an error. Now as for fixing the error, I have no idea. You would need to use something else other than DateTime.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try using the generic type parameter syntax instead for defining the props. E.g., `const props = defineProps<{ now: DateTime; maxCityNameSize: number; }>();`

Comment: @kelsny this is interesting, you have a longer error message than I do, and a different one too. I need to read about this private/public aspect. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I went for a double-staged `props` declaration and the linter is happy (and the code is happy as well):

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const props = defineProps(['now', 'maxCityNameSize'])
const now = ref<DateTime>(props.now)
const maxCityNameSize = ref<number>(props.maxCityNameSize)
```